# Surjectivity of reductive group adjoint quotient on rational points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $k$ be a field, and let $G$ be a connected reductive group over $k$. Form the adjoint quotient $G \rightarrow G^{\mathrm{ad}}$, which is the quotient of $G$ by its center.

Is the map on $k$-rational points $G(k) \rightarrow G^{\mathrm{ad}}(k)$ surjective? If not, are there some conditions when this is true?

It is definitely true if $k$ is algebraically closed.

I am particularly interested in the case where $k = \mathbb{R}$. A similar statement seems to be claimed in the proof of Proposition 5.7(a) in Milne's notes on Shimura varieties (https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/svi.pdf). Is there some Galois cohomology argument here?

Comment: Over $\mathbb{R}$, the (topological) identity component of $G(\mathbb{R})$ maps onto the identity component of $G^{\text{ad}}\mathbb{R})$ (because the map on the tangent spaces is surjective). It doesn't map onto all of $G^{\text{ad}}\mathbb{R})$ in general (even for $\text{SL}_2$).